# foreach jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a function to work for each `.download_now` element.

I have used the two below with no luck, any idea why?

```
$(".download_now").each.tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
$(".download_now").each(tooltip({ effect: 'slide'}));
```

---

Neither answer will work, I'm trying it on the following: 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Answer (score 3):

[**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) takes a function as an argument. Within that function you can use `this` to refer to the current element:

```
$(".download_now").each(function(){
    $(this).tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the tooltip call inside a function.

`each()` will then call the function for each iteration, passing the current element as `this`.

Like so:

```
$(".download_now").each(function(){
  $(this).tooltip({ effect: 'slide'})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function into the each method. Typically, an anonymous function is used like so:

```
$('.download_now').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Each DOM object can be referenced using `this` within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.each()`. Just do:

```
$(".download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
```

(like the [first page of the showcase](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html) shows)